# cannot launch script.py with python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.6

I'm not very confortable with coding yet, but I look forward to learn. I'm tryna launch a python script which works perfectly (after many issues that i could solve thank to stackoverflow) on my Mac.

Now i'm trying to make it work on ubuntu18.04 as I have an old laptop which the bot is supposed to run as long as it survives.

So the bot is InstaPy (https://github.com/timgrossmann/InstaPy), I have cloned it and setup the "quickstart.py" script as it's set up on my MacOS.

When i try to run it with `python3 script.py` here's what happens :

```
InstaPy Version: 0.6.7
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "/home/donny/InstaPy"
Error, unable to determine correct filename for Nonebit linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart.py", line 31, in <module>
    headless_browser=False)
  File "/home/donny/Téléchargements/InstaPy-master/instapy/instapy.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.logger,
  File "/home/donny/Téléchargements/InstaPy-master/instapy/browser.py", line 110, in set_selenium_local_session
    driver_path = geckodriver_path or get_geckodriver()
  File "/home/donny/Téléchargements/InstaPy-master/instapy/browser.py", line 36, in get_geckodriver
    bin_path, sym_path = gdd.download_and_install()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 177, in download_and_install
    show_progress_bar=show_progress_bar)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 129, in download
    download_url = self.get_download_url(version, os_name=os_name, bitness=bitness)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py", line 324, in get_download_url
    raise RuntimeError(info_message)
RuntimeError: Error, unable to determine correct filename for Nonebit linux
```

So I have tried to check in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/webdriverdownloader/webdriverdownloader.py to see what is raising the error.

[webdriverdownload.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufKaB.png)

[webdriverdownload-runtimeerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnx9D.png)

So I see the problem is around the API geckodriver but i cannot say what file/asset/date is missing on my Instapy config ! :(

Hope this is specific enough, thank you for your help !

Andre

Comment: The README.md for that git project says you should install via pip instead of git cloning it. You probably want to delete the cloned repository run a command like `pip3 install instapy --user` to install.

Comment: It tells you that the 'bitness' of your operating system (32 bit or 64 bit I assume) cannot be determined and so it cannot generate the filename to aautomatically download the correct driver. You'll have to dig deeper yourself why this happens. Try to look in the `get_architecture_bitness` method in the library. For future reference: don't post screenshots because we cannot copypaste it. Copy-paste the relevant (and only the relevant) code into your post and wrap it in code-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Add whatever Bit your system is in file /webdriverdownloader.py" on line 129.

```
download_url = self.get_download_url(version, os_name=os_name, bitness="64")
```

I wrote "64" as I know my system is 64 bit.